# Cloudkit dashboard unexpected server error

Tags: ios, cloudkit

When I want to use Cloudkit, I found that I can't manage the data by Cloudkit dashboard. The page tips me a message "Unexpected server error". How can I solve this problem? Here shows this error screenshot.

[image]

**[Update]**

Full error log:

> ERROR TITLE Unexpected server error.
>
> IS FATAL true
>
> TYPE server
>
> APPLICATION NAME Dashboard
>
> BUILD NUMBER 15BDev63
>
> TIME Tue Mar 24 2015 08:43:06 GMT+0100 (CET) (1427182986565)
>
> HOST icloud.developer.apple.com
>
> USER AGENT Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2)
>   AppleWebKit/600.4.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0.4 Safari/600.4.10
>
> ENVIRONMENT unknown
>
> RECENT LOG MESSAGES Tue, 24 Mar 2015 07:43:06 GMT: INFO: --> Request
>   1: GET to
>   https://ckdashboardws.icloud.apple.com/bootstrap?request_uuid=e7516168-dcfe-4ed5-aa17-dc3a5a97ffb6,
>   headers: Content-Type=text/plain, body: (empty) <-- Response 1: 500
>   (294ms), headers: Cache-Control=no-cache, no-store, private,
>   Content-Type=application/json; charset=UTF-8,
>   X-Apple-Request-UUID=f05681b8-1f1c-4af5-a534-5f6531c5a463 body:
>   {"errorReason":"Internal Server
>   Error","errorCode":500,"requestUUID":"f05681b8-1f1c-4af5-a534-5f6531c5a463"}
>   Tue, 24 Mar 2015 07:43:06 GMT: DEBUG: CloudKit: ErrorCatcher dialog
>   invoked. Tue, 24 Mar 2015 07:43:06 GMT: DEBUG: SC.Module: Attempting
>   to load 'cloudkit/error_catcher' Tue, 24 Mar 2015 07:43:06 GMT: DEBUG:
>   SC.Module: Module 'cloudkit/error_catcher' is not loaded, loading now.
>   Tue, 24 Mar 2015 07:43:06 GMT: DEBUG: SC.Module: Loading CSS file in
>   'cloudkit/error_catcher' ->
>   '/applications/dashboard/15BDev63/cloudkit/error_catcher/15BDev63/en-us/stylesheet.css'
>   Tue, 24 Mar 2015 07:43:06 GMT: DEBUG: SC.Module: Loading JavaScript
>   file in 'cloudkit/error_catcher' ->
>   '/applications/dashboard/15BDev63/cloudkit/error_catcher/15BDev63/en-us/javascript.js'
>   Tue, 24 Mar 2015 07:43:06 GMT: DEBUG: SC.Module: Module
>   'cloudkit/error_catcher' finished loading. Tue, 24 Mar 2015 07:43:06
>   GMT: DEBUG: SC.Module: Evaluating and invoking callbacks for
>   'cloudkit/error_catcher'. Tue, 24 Mar 2015 07:43:06 GMT: DEBUG:
>   SC.Module: Module 'cloudkit/error_catcher' has completed loading,
>   invoking callbacks.

Comment: I started getting this issue, have raised it in the dev forums: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/266093?tstart=0 and also filed a bug: http://openradar.appspot.com/20272273

Comment: My problem may stem from the fact that when logging in to the iPhone Simulator (Settings > iCloud), I used my Apple Developer accounts Apple ID. This may have messed things up on the backend that now causes the problem when trying to log into the CloudKit Dashboard.

Comment: My issue was fixed. For any others that come across this, try logging into iCloud on a hardware device (not the simulator) with your Apple Developer ID account, you can also try to verify the account (though I had already verified it, it was the logging into the hardware that fixed the issue for me).

Comment: The comment above from RogeSoft was extremely helpful when I encountered this today.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to just manage your CloudKit data. There have been incompatible changes to the CloudKit containers during the beta's. Is your container created during the beta phase? If you keep having this problem and don't have valuable data in your container, then try resetting it. Click on Deployment and then on Reset development environment

Comment: I afraid that I still have this problem. An alert box popup when I enter cloudkit dashboard. Because of that I cann't do any operation.

Comment: Maybe you could try setting up a new container. If you still have a problem, then I think the only option left is contacting Apple.

Comment: Just to add to this. I got the same issue, unable to access a container. Tried resetting the developer environment in Deployment to no avail. Had to just create and use a new container. Tried contacting Apple but no reply.

Comment: @RIs - sort of got it working by creating a new container but gave up on iCloud. Just using Dropbox now in my app.

Comment: @amergin - ok, interesting to know you switched, am going to keep slogging away with CloudKit/iCloud for now.

Answer (score 0):

For my case the Apple ID associated with my developer account was not activated for iCloud.  You can determine if it is or isn't by going to https://www.icloud.com and trying to sign in with your developer Apple ID.  If you can't then you won't be able to sign in to the dashboard either.

What I ended up doing was going to My Apple ID (https://appleid.apple.com/) and reverifying my Apple ID address.  Once this was completed I was able to login to both www.icloud.com and the iCloud CloudKit dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem and looked everywhere for a solution, but had no luck.

Finally, I realised that this started happening immediately after I added a record to the iCloud (CloudKit) database from one of my devices, so I thought deleting all records might work.

This wasn't too easy as I, like you, couldn't log into the dashboard, however I ran the following code snippet in my application for each entity in my database, and that fixed the problem.

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ application: UIApplication) {
    let publicDatabase = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase

    let allRecordsQuery = CKQuery(recordType: "ENTITY", predicate: NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE", []))

    publicDatabase.perform(allRecordsQuery, inZoneWith: nil) { (records, error) in
        for record in records! {
            publicDatabase.delete(withRecordID: record.recordID, completionHandler: { (deletedRecord, error) in
                if error == nil {
                    print("Deleted " + (deletedRecord?.recordName)!)
                } else {
                    print(error!)
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Replace `"ENTITY"` with every type of record in your database and run again.

So if you have just two entities: Pet and Task, first set `"ENTITY"` to `"Pet"` and run the application. Then set the `"ENTITY"` to `"Task"` and run the application again.

I realise that your question was asked a while ago, but this bug clearly still hasn't been fixed and so I hope my solution helps anybody else who has this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this same error message yesterday when trying to access the CloudKit Dashboard. I had previously accessed it with no problem.  After trying several of the above suggestions with no luck, I called Apple.  Apparently it was a system wide problem.  That allowed me to stop messing up my code looking for the problem and just move on to another task. So, if nothing else seems to be working, that might be worth checking.